# Make parallel processing -j command

Tags: makefile

I was trying to run processes parallel in a makefile with -j2 command. Everything thing was fine till i got this while "Make archive"

```
/opt/sunstudio12.1//bin/CC +w -DSOLARIS_THREADS -i -DRW_NO_STL \
    -U__LP64__ -library=%none,iostream,no%Cstd -D_USE_SMARTHEAP_ \
    -DNO_SYBASE -mt -DRW_MULTI_THREAD -D_REENTRANT -g -DTINY_DEBUG \
    -DRWDEBUG=1 -URW_HEADER_WITH_EXTENSION -DMEM_DEBUG=1 -xtarget=generic \
    -m64 -I/opt/sunstudio12.1/prod//include/CC/rw7/ \
    -I/view/grvobad2_mm71_lsv/vobs/bgw/BGwSOURCE/common/mrl \
    -I/view/grvobad2_mm71_lsv/vobs/bgw/BGwSOURCE/common/sharedmemory \
    -I/view/grvobad2_mm71_lsv/vobs/bgw/BGwSOURCE/common \
    -I/view/grvobad2_mm71_lsv/vobs/bgw/BGwSOURCE/database \
    -I/view/grvobad2_mm71_lsv/vobs/bgw/BGwSOURCE -I/opt/oracle/10//rdbms/demo \
    -I/opt/oracle/10//rdbms/public -I/opt/oracle/10//plsql/public \
    -I/opt/oracle/10//network/public \
    -I/vobs/bgw/sw-3pp-cm/emm3/SunOS/pgsql/7.1.3/include \
    -I/vobs/bgw/sw-3pp-cm/mm70/x86/tcl/tcl-8.5.7/unix/include \
    -I/vobs/bgw/sw-3pp-cm/mm70/x86/libcurl/libcurl-7.19.5/include \
    -I/opt/sunstudio12.1/prod//include/CC/rw7 \
    -I/vobs/bgw/sw-3pp-cm/mm70/x86/SmartHeap_9smp//include \
    -I/vobs/bgw/sw-3pp-cm/mm70/x86/pccts/include \
    -o _tdebug/solarisx64/AParser.o \
    -c AParser.cc
```

Now what does this actually mean. It is all greek to me. There has been some sort of a problem here but since the message is not comprehendable , i am not able to decipher the problem. Can anybody help me with this?.

Comment: That's a C++ compiler command line with a ton of include paths (`-I`), it is supposed to compile `AParser.cc` to `_tdebug/solarisx64/AParser.o`. Is there an error message of sort to go along with that?

Answer (score 2):

The actual error message is missing, your post only shows the command line arguments used for compiling the source file AParser.cc

When using parallel builds with for example `make -j2` the actual error messages can be hard to find. However, the error should also show up directly at the end of the output if you type just `make`. Please post this output for more information.