# PARALLEL submakes

Tags: makefile

I have been working with makefiles to reduce their compilation time. I have 2 questions

1) I found that if i run make in a sub directory of the main directory, it runs perfectly. Does it mean the subdirectory is independent of the other sub-directories and can be run in parallel?

2) how to run sub-makes being called recursively in parallel? tell me something other than -j

Comment: Multiple duplicates (same user), e.g. [use of PARALLEL in make](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942991/use-of-parallel-in-make) and [Make parallel processing -j command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883066/make-parallel-processing-j-command)

Comment: the questions are different and i am not getting a sufficient reply. Since i am researching, i get a new problem each day !!!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I simplified a makefile, as a prerequisite to other changes to add features and speed things up.

The simplification included removing use or recursive make. I was surprised to discover that the build was now twice as fast (from 40 minutes to 20 minutes). I could also now use the -j option, thus improving speed even more.

I then made some other changes that had a smaller effect.

Comment: How to remove the sub make? i want to run the make of all the directories. Should i mention all the names?

Comment: @ankit If all makes are independent then it **should** not do any harm, but why not just call them from a script. I could not see **specifically** what the problem was with mine. My boss had added several uses of recursion, I could not say what was wrong with them, but when remover it was easier to read and faster. I am not anti recursion only anti recursive make. Make in declarative not procedural, so should not include recursive procedures. Re-factoring may take a while, it took me ~15 hours, and mine was mostly in good shape to start with. See http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/